# How to fix error "Error copying library com.mojang:netty:1.8.8" for MCP 1.7.10

Tags: java, minecraft

I've been trying to decompile MCP 1.7.10 but I keep getting this error. The error says it has something to do with Minecraft 1.8.8 but I want 1.7.10. I don't know if that has to do anything with it. Here is the error I keep getting:

```
== MCP 9.04 (data: 9.08, client: 1.7.10, server: 1.7.10) ==
"scalac" is not found on the PATH.  Scala files will not be recompiled
# found ff, ff patches, srgs, name csvs, doc csvs, param csvs, astyle, astyle config, rg, ss
Looking in C:\Users\jacks\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions for mc installs... OK
Copying assets... OK
Parsing JSON file... OK
Looking for minecraft main jar... OK
> Checking libraries...
        Copying library netty... Error copying library com.mojang:netty:1.8.8
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the netty library in your .minecraft folder or it is in the wrong version.

If you want MCP to be able to decompile the game, there should be a `1.8.8` folder in `~/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/netty`

I have encountered this issue twice and fixed this in two different ways:

- Retrieve it from another installation
- Rename the existing folder and the inside jar `1.8.8` (instead of `1.6` or `1.7.7` in my case)